# How to configure workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

This may be very simple but I am very very new to SharePoint and I am trying to create workflows for a change management process. Can someone tell me how to configure a workflow to:

Assign a task to the project manager for approval 
AND
Send a notification email to the applications manager based on the system selected in the form (there are 5 people who handle 9 systems so it will go to the person who handles each particular system).

Thank you so much in advance - this has been driving me mad!

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples available on the internet, In your case you need a SharePoint designer workflow.

- [SharePoint 2013 Approval Workflow With Dynamic Approvers From Another List](http://techbrij.com/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-dynamic-approvers)
- [SharePoint 2013 Workflows](http://sp2013.pro/2013/02/creating-spd-2013-workflows-part-13-extremely-simple-workflow-and-default-task-form/)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 types of workflows in SP,

1. **OOB Workflow** - http://blog.csdn.net/tristan_dong/article/details/8295105
2. **Designer Workflow** - https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/advanced-microsoft-sharepoint/creating-custom-workflows-with-sharepoint-designer-2013.cfm
3. **Custom (visual studio) Workflow**

Some simple process like, submit and approval, bug tracking, can be done in OOB itself.

If your problem is not solved after exploring OOB link above, goto Designer workflow.